# what is the difference between done and callback ? (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, function

What is the difference between a callback and done inside a function? I was using a package of passport google auth20, here return done(null, existingUser) is used. what is the main functionality or speciality of done? why not callback?

```
function(a, b, callback){
callback(something)
}
```

and

```
 async (request, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
 try {
 let existingUser = await User.findOne({ 'google.id': profile.id });
 // if user exists return the user 
 if (existingUser) {
 return done(null, existingUser);
 }
```

Comment: This is just an implementation detail. `done` is just a function that will be called, and is in theory a callback. Some developers choose to use a more meaningful parameter name instead of just `callback`.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this out.

Comment: As there are no other answers, I've copied my comment as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an implementation detail. `done` is just a function that will be called, and is in theory a callback. Some developers choose to use a more meaningful parameter name instead of just `callback`.